# Scale to viewport with Google Web Designer

Tags: viewport

I built this site via Google Web Designer (ZippyDriver.com) and want it to scale to my viewport but haven't figured out how to do it. I don't want a responsive site — just want it to stretch to the screen if possible. Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change all your elements size to % instead of px dimensions?

You can achieve this by selecting any of your elements, lets say an IMG, then in its Properties -> Size and Position be sure it shows the IMG dimensions in % not in px.

After that, try resizing the viewport and see if it works.